# run() method is not invoked by Thread instance

Tags: java, multithreading

I have started learning Multi Threading in Java. I am writing program for creating Thread.

```
public class CreateThread extends Thread{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    **Thread t1 = new Thread();
       t1.start()**;                //   This does not call run method

        CreateThread t1 = new CreateThread();
        t1.start();                  // This calls run method
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread started");
    }   
}
```

If start() is invoked by CreateThread instance run method is invoked.
but if start() is invoked by Thread instance ( highlighted by bold letters) run method is not invoked.

Even instance of Thread class is separate thread then why run() is not invoked.
Please explain how thread is created internally in Java.

Comment: You probably need to learn OO and inheritance before you dive into multithreading.

Comment: `Thread  t1` is a different object and it is not a `CreateThread` object

Comment: Thanks for the info Thomas. I know the concepts of inheritance and oo. I could not co relate and get answer hence posted question. Please let me know the explanation. It will be of great help me to understand concepts thoroughly. thank you

Comment: The run () method must go inside the thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
Thread t1 = new Thread();
t1.start()
```

*does* call `run()`, but it's calling `Thread.run()`, not `CreateThread.run()` (because you've created t1 as a `Thread`, not a `CreateThread`)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have some misunderstandings about inheritance and polymorphism. You seemed to have mixed them up.

> CreateThread is subclass of Thread. If instance of CreateThread can invoke run() then why instance of Thread cannot invoke?

Because you don't have an object of `CreateThread` here:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread();
```

If you put a `CreateThread` object into a `Thread` variable, and call `start`, `run` will be called:

```
Thread t1 = new CreateThread();
t1.start();
```

This is because `t1` actually holds a `CreateThread` object.

*Inheritance* is what allows you to assign a `CreateThread` object to a `Thread` variable. Instances of derived classes can be assigned to variables of base classes.

Being able to call `start` on a `Thread` variable and see the `run` method of `CreateThread` being called is due to *Polymorphism*.